# Al pulsar fuera de un elemento cerrarlo

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo un botón que muestra y oculta el mismo `div` y le paso una variable para saber en que estado está, pero quiero que al hacer click fuera de ese elemento se cierre

```js
var mostrar = true;

$('#notifica').on('click', function(){
  if(mostrar==true){
    muestraDiv();
    mostrar=false;
  }
  else
  {
    cierraDiv();
    mostrar=true;
  }
  
});

function muestraDiv() {
    $('#menuNotifica').css("display","block");
}

function cierraDiv() {
    $('#menuNotifica').css("display","none");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.1.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lKuwvrZot6UHsBSfcMvOkWwlCMgc0TaWr+30HWe3a4ltaBwTZhyTEggF5tJv8tbt" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="col-12">
  <div clas="container">
   <div class="disInline" style="position: relative">
     <a class="btnNotifica" id="notifica"><i class="fas fa-bell"></i> pulsar</a>
      <div class="notis" id="menuNotifica" style="display: none;">
         <span class="with-arrow">
           <span class="bg-primary"></span>
         </span>
         <h2>Notificaciones</h2>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
              <a href="" class="pnotia">
                  <div class="divNotia">
                    <div class="titnoti">Titulo notificación <span class="pull-right"><i class="far fa-circle"></i></span></div>
                    <p class="pnoti">Aquí el contenido de la notificación</p>
                  </div>
              </a>     
          </div>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Oye, te faltó poner tu html, así nunca se va a renderizar.  Las preguntas que buscan ayuda con la depuración deben incluir el comportamiento esperado, un problema específico o error, y el código más corto necesario para reproducirlo en la propia pregunta. Las preguntas sin un planteamiento claro del problema no son útiles para otros lectores. Véase: Cómo crear un [mcve]

Comment: Perdona @RuslanLópez con las prisas se me fue, ya está planteado el ejemplo

Comment: No sé que has intentado, pero yo pondría algo así como un overlay ( obviamente invisible ) sobre el resto de los elementos pero no sobre eel menú, que aparezca al abrir el menú y que desaparezca al darle click.

Comment: Alguna ayuda con el código? por favor!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay algunas cosas por mejorar en tu código, por ejemplo, jQuery dispone de un método `toggle()` para mostrar / ocultar, dependiendo del estado actual del elemento. Gracias a eso, puedes evitar crear una función para cada opción y evitas analizar si está visible o no, deja que jQuery lo haga por ti.

Ahora, debes escuchar los clics en el documento para saber dónde se realizó y analizar si el menú está abierto para cerrarlo. Comentarios en el `if`.

```js
$(document).click(function(event) {
  if(!$(event.target).closest('#notifica').length      // No es el enlace (ni sus hijos)
  && !$(event.target).closest('#menuNotifica').length  // No es la ventana (ni sus hijos)
  && $('#menuNotifica').is(":visible")) {              // Y la ventana está visible
    $('#menuNotifica').hide();
  }        
});

$('#notifica').on('click', function(){
    $('#menuNotifica').toggle();
});
```

```css
#menuNotifica { background:#eee; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.1.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lKuwvrZot6UHsBSfcMvOkWwlCMgc0TaWr+30HWe3a4ltaBwTZhyTEggF5tJv8tbt" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="col-12">
  <div clas="container">
   <div class="disInline" style="position: relative">
     <a class="btnNotifica" id="notifica"><i class="fas fa-bell"></i> pulsar</a>
      <div class="notis" id="menuNotifica" style="display: none;">
         <span class="with-arrow">
           <span class="bg-primary"></span>
         </span>
         <h2>Notificaciones</h2>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
              <a href="" class="pnotia">
                  <div class="divNotia">
                    <div class="titnoti">Titulo notificación <span class="pull-right"><i class="far fa-circle"></i></span></div>
                    <p class="pnoti">Aquí el contenido de la notificación</p>
                  </div>
              </a>     
          </div>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ohh vaya es brillante y me has optimizado el código que bueno!! muchas gracias @Triby